# defining the last column to be printed in python

Tags: python, printing

I have a table with some data and I want to able to print just the first 4 columns to put a ratio columns just after.

```
for pref in range(1, len(table)) :
    print(table[pref][0].rjust(10), end=" ") 
    for age in range(1, len(table[0])):
        print(table[pref][age].rjust(5), end=" ")
    print()
```

I was able to do it just changing the `len(table[0])` for the columns number, but I want to leave the range like that and just change the print.

Is it possible?

Comment: tip: use pandas.

Comment: @Wilian, cant use it. is there anther way? something like "stop printing after column X"

Comment: change value in `range` - don't waste time for other ideas. And if you want to use different values then maybe use variable with value `len(table[0])` or `5`

Comment: code could be more readable if you would use `for row in table[1:]` instead of `for pref in range(1, len(table))`, and `for item  in row[1:]: print( item.rjust(5), end=" ")`